# Errors when trying to get a connection to cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I'm trying to create a Java program that uses a Cassandra database.
I'm 'trying' to use Hector client but when I run I'm getting some errors. I have searched on the internet but could find a fix that worked for me (it's probably something obvious).

Libs I included in my build path:

```
hector
libthrift-0.9.1
slf4j-simple-1.75
```

Errors im getting:

```
[main] INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.CassandraHostRetryService - Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
[main] INFO me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.JmxMonitor - Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_Test Cluster:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/InvalidRequestException
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.factory.HThriftClientFactoryImpl.createClient(HThriftClientFactoryImpl.java:42)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.createClient(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:179)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.ConcurrentHClientPool.<init>(ConcurrentHClientPool.java:61)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.RoundRobinBalancingPolicy.createConnection(RoundRobinBalancingPolicy.java:68)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:56)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.AbstractCluster.<init>(AbstractCluster.java:67)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster.<init>(ThriftCluster.java:21)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createCluster(HFactory.java:197)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:144)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.getOrCreateCluster(HFactory.java:133)
    at org.codox.lobbyserver.data.CassandraAccess.test(CassandraAccess.java:39)
    at org.codox.lobbyserver.Server.main(Server.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.thrift.InvalidRequestException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Any help is welcome, if you need more info tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That class seems to be in the `cassandra-thrift` library which you can find [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-thrift/2.0.3).

Comment: thank you for you respond that was indeed the library i was missing but now i got the error: org/apache/cassandra/thrift/InvalidRequestException : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0. but i have changed the compiler settings to 1.6 but still getting error. any ideas?

Comment: @user1971401 Perhaps the version you got was compiled with Java 7.

Comment: took a lower version and it worked. but now i got another classDefNotFound ;p com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet happen to have a link for this one too? thx

Comment: @user Yes, that's part of [`Guava`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava). You can find these yourselves pretty easily by just searching `jar <the class>`.